# boost asio multicast rejoining a group

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, boost-asio

I've implemented a set of successfully functioning multicast readers but periodically and randomly during the day one or more of them loses a block of 2 minutes of data. My working theory is that either the router's periodic request for report is getting lost or the host report is getting lost. So I would like to preemptively send a report to the router on a some interval. So the question is how would I do that? I don't see a rejoin method in boost:asio for multicast. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
// code snippet from the constructor method
// 
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(listen_address, mcPort);
socket_.open(listen_endpoint.protocol());
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
socket_.bind(listen_endpoint);

boost::asio::socket_base::receive_buffer_size option(65536*16);                    
socket_.set_option(option);
//
// Join the multicast group.
//    
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));

m_TimerRejoinGroup.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
m_TimerRejoinGroup.async_wait(boost::bind(&Feed::handleRejoin, this));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your direct question, there is no rejoin option, but you can leave and join again

```
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::leave_group(multicast_address));
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicast_address));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that potentially open a small window that would introduce the possibility of a gap?

Comment: Yes, yes it would.  But you're trying to solve a deficiency in the network/OS level (IGMP multicast request/response packets either being lost or not being sent often enough) with an application level response.  The only other solution I can recommend is open a new socket on the same group, even if on a different port, to force the network to join again, but if the OS still thinks it is a part of the group, it will not help, since from it's point of view it's still joined and doesn't need to send another JOIN_GROUP message.

Comment: The second socket seems like it would be good to experiment with. What I was wondering is if there's a way to write a join request using low level methods/functions that would essentially sneak by the OS in such a way that it would not sense it as a join report and therefore always send it out on the wire.

Comment: @Al Then sorry, not that I can think of.  Even at the POSIX api level the socket options are for join/leave.  Unless your OS provides a way to force a resend of the joined group information, you might have to solve the source of the dropped group.

Comment: Dave, I am running it now with your suggestion and sometimes the leave/join occur in the same microsecond sometimes as great as 100 micros. I have seem some gapping as a result, albeit small gaps and my gapfiller seems to be doing a good job of quickly filling the gaps. so for now this might be a workaround solution. Thanks